# Differentiate i from union set, from which original set is it coming?

Tags: python, set

I am so new to programming language, so please kindly help me with this issue on Python.

I got excel data like this:

```
data1=[[161.0, 48.0], [160.0, 96.0], [163.0, 61.0], [160.0, 115.0], [173.0, 105.0]]

data2=[[180.0, 91.0], [180.0, 80.0], [174.0, 94.0], [170.0, 101.0], [172.0, 78.0]]
```

Suppose I just want to care about the X point of each data, so I got this:

```
unique_X1=[160, 161, 163, 173]

unique_X2=[170, 172, 174, 180]
```

Then, I could make the union as set X:

```
set([160, 161, 163, 170, **172**, **173**, 174, 180])
```

So, what I have to do now is, making a set of "cut points" if the i and i+1 from union set is coming from different data set (unique_X1 or unique_X2). And the value of cut point will be (i + [i+1])/2

For example, 172 is coming from unique_X2 and 173 coming from unique_X1, so the cut point is (172+173)/2=172.5

Here is what i have done so far, would really appreciate if some can help me for the rest. I believe i have to use loop, but i just don't know how. thanks in advance

```
import xlrd

#getting data
book = xlrd.open_workbook('sampledata1.xlsx')
sheet1 = book.sheet_by_name('Female')
sheet2 = book.sheet_by_name('Male')
data1 = [[sheet1.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet1.ncols)] for r in range(sheet1.nrows)]
data2 = [[sheet2.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet2.ncols)] for r in range(sheet2.nrows)]
print data1
print data2

X1=[int(i[0]) for i in data1]
X2=[int(i[0]) for i in data2]
# print X1
# print X2

#collecting same points
def unique(X1):
    return list(set(X1))
# print unique(X1)

def unique(X2):
    return list(set(X2))
# print unique(X2)

#sorting data
sort_unique_X1 = sorted(unique(X1))
sort_unique_X2 = sorted(unique(X2))
print sort_unique_X1
print sort_unique_X2

#union X1 and X2
X=set(unique(X1)).union(unique(X2))
print X


#generating cut points
# cut_X = []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cut_X = []
for i,j in zip(X,X[1:]):
    if i in unique_X1 and j in unique_X2:
        cut_X.append(0.5*(i+j))
    elif i in unique_X2 and j in unique_X1:
        cut_X.append(0.5*(i+j))
```

for the current numbers `print cut_X` should produce `[166.5, 172.5, 173.5]`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help... but the cut point between one data and other data is  not necessarily +0.5, for example for data 170 and 172 the cut point will be 171 :D

Comment: Ah.! Agreed :)

Please accept it as an answer if it has solved your problem:)